# Absolute positioning image with overflow hidden parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div `.outer` which I use as a 'window' with an image appearing underneath and a hotspot. The parent div is the width of the device up to 960px.

In my example, for mobile (360px width), I have the cyclist's front wheel appearing in the centre of the window but as I expand the window the image slowly moves to the left pushing the wheel out of sight.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer {
  border: 20px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.img {
  left: -26%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <img src="http://i345.photobucket.com/albums/p397/chieflagos/sports_zpsv08bhwa3.jpg" class="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the image to move to the right as the window is being expanded so the wheel stays in the middle of the window.

I have tried using CSS `vw` and `vh` but to no avail.

Comment: For me, you need more than css to do it. I meant you need Javascript a perform it.

Comment: If you keep the bicycle's front wheel in the center, won't you get whitespace to the left of it on a wide enough screen? Also, does the hotspot serve a purpose as part of this question?

Comment: @AndrewMessier - I was going to use a media query to change the left: -26px when it got a tablet/desktop so the whitespace wouldn't appear. The hotspot is not really part of the issue so I will remove it.